Identify a TV show/episode like 'Black Mirror'
Timespan: no more than 4-5 years old
Set in/Watched in: UK
Watched on: internet catch-up (Netflix, Amazon etc.)
Format: TV/Short episodes
For ages I assumed that this was an episode of 'Black Mirror' but, after going through the episodes on IMDB I cannot find it, therefore I assume it must be something else.
What I remember:

I recall it being a series of interlinked murders, maybe one leading to another (?).
One took place in a subway or under a bridge and involved something in a rucksack.
One took place in a young woman's house (This I think was the last murder) and there was a social media aspect to it where She was watching a feed and suddenly it became clear She was the intended victim. I recall her watching a feed from the killer and seeing herself on it.

That's about all I can remember about it. It might be a Black Mirror episode but I can't see one that fits...
Any help would be greatly appreciated

The show that immediately springs to mind for me is Inside No.9, but I'd have to look it up to be sure.

I watched Inside No. 9 a couple months back and this doesn't ring any bells. Having said that, I haven't seen series 3, but that's from earlier this year so doesn't really fit the timeline of 4-5 years.

No not 'Inside No. 9'

Sounds like "Darknet"
It had a very similar premise to Black Mirror-- where each episode was different and revolved around technology, mainly the internet.  Each episode was slightly intertwined though. It was available on Netflix.

"Each episode features several different stories that revolve around people in various different horror-related situations. Each story is related to a website called "Darknet", where people can post questions or answers to various topics such as what would be the best way to dispose of a corpse."

Here's a clip from the first episode (I had a hard time finding a trailer besides short teaser clips):




That's it ! Canadian not English - I knew I'd get something wrong...
